# How to batch a cocktail with a muddled ingredient?

Tags: cocktails, serving, bartending

I'd like to prepare Gin Basil Smashes for a large event but it calls for muddling basil leaves for each serving which will be too slow. Before I experiment, is there already a known way to prepare a syrup or cordial ahead of time (perhaps flavored with lots of muddled basil) so that it can be mixed quickly when it's time to serve?

Answer (score 2):

**How to batch a cocktail with a muddled ingredient?**

For your **Gin Basil Smashes**, try using a [Basil Simple Syrup](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/247474/basil-simple-syrup/), but in order to use less less syrup in your mix triple the amount of basil leaves you use in making the basic basil syrup.

This is not a proven way to help you out, but I am confident it may work.

> **Basil Simple Syrup**
>
> Use this basil simple syrup to flavor summer's most refreshing cocktails, mocktails, lemonades, and frozen treats. Fresh basil leaves are steeped in sugar and water to create a sweet herbal syrup.
>
> - 1 cup water
> - 1 cup white sugar
> - 1 cup fresh basil leaves
>
> **Directions**
>
> Combine water, sugar, and basil leaves in a small saucepan. Bring to a boil, stirring until sugar dissolves. Reduce heat and simmer for 1 minute. Remove from heat and let syrup steep for 30 minutes.
>
> Drain syrup through a mesh strainer into a sterilized glass jar; discard basil leaves. Let cool, then cover and store in the refrigerator for up to 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

If you are batching for a single event and all of your batch is to be used all at once, there is no reason why you can't just blitz *blanched* basil syrup into your gin and lemon mix and then refrigerate til needed.

Jeffrey Morgenthaler has a great trick for this that he uses for mojitos but there's no reason why it wouldn't work for GBS.

> A trick for herb-infused syrups that won't turn brown, and a mojito recipe that you can make for a group, without spending the whole night muddling.

You can find the full recipe [here](https://food52.com/blog/10845-how-to-blanch-herbs-for-syrups-a-mojito)